# English Corpus needed

Tags: nlp, corpus

I'm looking for free full-text English corpus, which supposed to contains only plain texts without any annotations (English books for example).

please, any help?

Comment: hi Reda! did you have difficulties finding one that suited your needs? it would be helpful to add that kind of information to improve your question. for me, the first few results for an `english corpus` query on google yield results that should be of help. the BYU-BNC site seems helpful.

Comment: BYU-BNC is not a free!

Comment: you're absolutely right! added some comment's in Pierre's and alvas' answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know "Project Gutenberg"? There are plenty of books in raw text format.

http://www.gutenberg.org/

Comment: look for the `Plain Text UTF-8` versions!

Comment: why did I get a downvote for this answer. please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Brown corpus in `NLTK`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> for i in brown.sents():
...     print i
...     break
... 
['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', 'Friday', 'an', 'investigation', 'of', "Atlanta's", 'recent', 'primary', 'election', 'produced', '``', 'no', 'evidence', "''", 'that', 'any', 'irregularities', 'took', 'place', '.']
```

Comment: nice! you can also see a list with more at http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html#annotated-text-corpora